# jmpress: Scrolling on Absolutely Positioned Element (Slide) with auto height

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

### [Live Site](http://srsgores.jit.su)

I have a site using jmpress, and I'm having a hard time getting scrolling on my content.  I'm able to scroll in Chrome by simply selecting text on the page and dragging down, but I'd like to achieve this in all browsers with native scroll, perhaps emulated by javascript.  I've checked a number of plugins to do this like jScrollpane and tinyScrollbar, but none of them will work without a height set and `overflow-y` set to scroll.  The second problem: even when I set the `overflow-y` to `scroll`, scrolling does not occur with the mousewheel.

Try this in the console: `$(".step").jScrollPane();`.  Nothing happens.  Set each step to have a `height` of 800px and `overflow-y` `scroll`, and scrolling works, but still this is only relative to the height of the window.  I need some way of calculating the size of the surrounding elements (relatively positioned) so that the height can be calculated when the user resizes the screen.

So is it possible to achieve scrolling on an absolutely positioned element (slide) and keep the height as auto using jmpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the window resize event of jquery to set your height dynamically after you set the height you could call the update method of tinyscrollbar to update the scrollbar.

Comment: Yup.  That's what I did, and it did work.  The only thing that didn't work was the scrolling.  Even with tinyscrollbar, or any of the others, the scroll event isn't fired at all, when the cursor is placed over an absolutely-positioned element.  This problem appears to be exclusive to absolutely-positioned elements...